# how to cast c++ smart pointer up and down

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

two clients communicate to each other on top of a message layer

in the message body, I need include a field pointing to any data type

From client A, I send the field as a `shared_ptr<TYPEA>` to the message layer.
I define this field as a `shared_ptr<void>` in the message layer.
But how can I convert this field back to `shared_ptr<TYPEA>` in client B?

Or should I define `shared_ptr<void>` in message layer as something else?

Thanks

Comment: Do the clients exist in separate processes, perhaps but not necessarily on different hosts?

Comment: The two clients are in the same process.    The stackoverflow doesn't show my question correctly.   It's shared_ptr< TYPEA > to shared_ptr< void > then back to shared_ptr< TYPEA > again.

Seems static_ptr_cast, dynamic_ptr_cast can't cast void to TYPEA

Comment: Actually my current implementation the TYPEA is a std::vector, but it may be std::string etc or any user defined classes. To define a common base class may not be possible.

Comment: reinterpret_cast can cast unrelatd pointers. But in std::tr1, I can only found static_pointer_cast, dynamic_pointer_cast. There is no reinterpret_pointer_cast. How could I use reinterpret cast for my shared_ptr? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using boost::shared_ptr then you can use the various XXX_ptr_cast<>() functions (static_ptr_cast, dynamic_ptr_cast...).

If you're using the MSVC 2010 version I haven't been able to find an implementation of these functions.  They may not be part of the standard.

Comment: The MSVC2010 version is  dynamic_pointer_cast: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982967.aspx

Comment: cast shared_ptr< void > var with std::tr1::static_pointer_cast< TYPEA >(var) does work. My mistake.

cast TYPEA to void then static_cast to TYPEA equivelent to reinterpret_cast

Answer (score 2):

If the shared_ptrs & pointed-to data aren't held in memory common to both clients (e.g. the clients run in different processes, and the data isn't in shared memory), the pointers from one client won't be valid for the other. You'll need to construct a representation of the pointed-to data and transmit that. The receiver constructs its own copy of the data in the messaging layer and passes a shared_ptr to that up to the client.

Answer (score 0):

If all possible data types that you plan on passing between clients inherit from some common base class, you can simply include a flag variable in the base class which indicates which derived type the current instance is.  Pass base-class pointers between clients, and then use `dynamic_cast` to downcast the base pointer to the appropriate derived type.